# Android studios global Bluetooth

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth

Ive been looking around for a way to implement Bluetooth across multiple activities using android studios in java . I’ve stumbled onto information asyncrunus services but havent had luck with implementation . I’m new to java .

Comment: Ask a specific question that someone may try to help with.

Comment: I’m just trying to figure out how to set up a Bluetooth connection in android studios that Is sustained when changing activities.

Comment: Their seems to be plenary of examples on how to implement it on only one activity but to suspain it across multiple activities has little to no documentation.